# "Run as JavaScript" does not work with my dart web app?

Tags: dart, dart2js

I cannot find the reason why my app does not work when compiled to JavaScript using dart2js. I have tried debugging my compiled JavaScript app using Google DevTools but found it very difficult to understand both the debugger and JavaScript code. You can find my web app on [GitHub](https://github.com/nawafnaim/wTutor). I suspect there is a conflict between compiled JavaScript code and imported third party JS libraries such as jquery but not sure. I highly appreciate your help.

Comment: The github project seems to lack some files (like pubspec.yaml). I wasn't able to run it.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look at my issue. I've just pushed the pubspec.yaml to my github repo. Please let me know if you can run it now or something else need to be pushed. Thank you.

Comment: have you tried `pub build --mode debug` to prevent minification?

Comment: @zoechi thank you for your comment. My problem was resolved by placing the dart.js script line after the app script line. But, I didn't know about 'pub build' before. I've tried your command but it throws 'Could not find an option named "mode".'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest is probably to add a few `print` statements into your code. With binary search it should be relatively easy to figure out when the VM and dart2js diverge.

Please report back, what the reason was and/or file a bug at http://dartbug.com/ if you believe that dart2js did it wrong.

Solution (as reported by OP): "dart.js should come after [the] app script line".

Comment: I added a print statement after main(). It prints ok on Dart VM but dart2js does not print that statement to FireFox console. It seems the compiled JS code is not visible to my browser. Nothing works in the app except for externally imported JS libraries. Even buttons and input boxes are not working.

Comment: Try to get the most simple page working. Remove all the Dart code except a print in main. In the server (or with Chrome dev-tools) see what files are loaded. If no print is executed I would guess that dart.js doesn't replace the dart script-tags with js script-tags. I haven't tested it, but maybe because the script tags are in the header and not in the body. So that's what I would look at next.

Comment: Thank you Florian. I found the problem. dart.js should come after my app script line. I think DartEditor should issue a warning if the placement of dart.js line is that important. After I made this change, the VM started displaying all dynamically generated buttons twice. And the JS version of the app is not behaving as expected. Throwing null pointer exceptions when the VM does not. I will post about these issues on another stackoverflow question. For this qustion, changing the position of the dart.js does the trick. Thank you again for ur time and help. Please add this solution 2 ur answer.